# Jnuit and Code files in different locations

Tags: unit-testing, ant

I am trying to run ANT script to execute a simple junit test case.
Now I have a requirement.

1. The executable file with my sample product will be in one location
2. My junit test cases will be in another location
3. Still I have to sync up and get the test case executed

Is there a way where I can ask my Junit to look another location for source.

Comment: How is this related to Maven?

Answer (score 0):

If your junit test cases live in another project then you will need to create a seperate build.xml for that project setup for unit tests.  Make sure this new build.xml references your sample product JAR as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Compile your source files as usual:

```
<javac srcdir="../${srcDir}/src" destdir="dist/src">
```

Compile your test files, including the compiled source in your classpath:

```
<javac srcdir="../${testDir}/test" destdir="dist/test">
   <classpath location="dist/src"/>
</javac>
```

Then include both these in the JUnit classpath:

```
<path id="junit.path">
    <pathelement location="dist/src" />
    <pathelement location="dist/test" />
    <fileset file="../Libraries/junit*.jar" />
    <fileset file="../Libraries/ant-junit*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="externalLibraries">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>          
</path>


<junit fork="yes" forkmode="once">
    <classpath refid="junit.path" />

    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${dist}/testresults">
        <fileset dir="dist/test">
            <include name="**/*Test.class" />
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>            
</junit>
```

See also [Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)